# How to run angular tests using protractor with safari under ubuntu?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, protractor

- I want to know if there is a good way to test angular application using protractor with safari.
- capabilities: [
  {
  browserName: 'safari',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  },
  ],
- I got this message when i tried to run my spec:
  E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: SafariDriverService
- I'm using ubuntu 18.04.5 / protractor 7.0.0 / webdriver-manager 12.1.7

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you need MacOS host to run safari browser. Thats the only OS were Safari can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is https://www.browserstack.com/ with this tool you can control the real MacOS machine and any browser you want (including older versions)

When configured correctly, tests can be ran from any OS including Ubuntu

BUT the license is pricey

Try to lookup cheaper analogues, is you have budget for any license at all